# How to derive the binomial theorem?

Tags: binomial-theorem

I saw the binomial theorem in some 11th grade book in my library. It was proved by induction. But there was no derivation of it. I do not like to memorize it.
So I'm hoping someone can show me a derivation for it and give hint for another way to derive it.
It would be great if you try to use high school mathematical tools if possible, so I can understand it.

$$
(x+y)^{n}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^{k}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{k}y^{n-k}.
$$

Comment: You have $n$ identical factors. From each factor you can either choose $x$ or $y$.

Comment: When we multiply $(x+y)(x+y)\cdots (x+y)$, note that we will be picking up either $x$ or $y$ from each factor. The coefficient of $x^{n-k}y^k$ is the same as the number of ways of picking $x$ from $n-k$ factors and picking $y$ from the other $k$. The number of ways of choosing $k$ of the $n$ factors is $\binom{n}{k}$ and hence this is the coefficient of $x^{n-k}y^k$. This proves the expression on the right hand side.

Comment: What do you mean by "It was proved by induction. But there was no derivation of it."? If there was a proof by induction, isn't that a derivation in itself?

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) has a number of proofs on it already as well.

Comment: @Arthur, the theorem was given, and proved by induction saying that this and this works, but there is nothing of how "this" has even come to be.

Comment: @ManasvChhabra What you're intending to ask is what led to its conjecturing. On the Wikipedia page of the Binomial Theorem go to the section labelled "History".

Comment: Oh I was just asking how did those guys came to know the formula. Some are saying it has to do with simple combinatorics, so I'm trying to understand that.